# Is there any method to regenerate cms/blocks in magento2 without sql file?

Tags: sql, magento, content-management-system, magento2

So far, I developed cms/blocks on staging server directly, therefore I have no any local dev environment.
Suddenly server HDD was crashed and i failed to restore data on server.
All my codes have been managing by git but can't find any certain files that are related to cms/blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of CMS blocks are stored in the database table `cms_block`. There is not backup in the filesystem.